# Does the 64-bit version of the OneDrive app have the file count limit?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, onedrive

I am running the 32-version of the OneDrive app on my Windows 10 laptop and apparently it has a 300,000 file max on synchs. That is, if the folder has more than 300k files in its entire folder tree, it will fail to back it up to the cloud. What's worse is that, at least the way it's working on our system, it does not produce any error messages and just spins its wheels indefinitely pretending to work.

Is the 64-bit version any better? Does it have the file count limit? If so, what is it? Error messaging any better? TIA!

Comment: At this point, Onedrive 64-bit is still a public preview. I cannot find any information about this.   https://www.techrepublic.com/article/microsoft-unveils-64-bit-version-of-onedrive/#:~:text=In%20a%20blog%20post%20published,you%20meet%20the%20necessary%20requirements.

Comment: I have to doubt that the file limit will be any different when it is released (speculation).  300k isn't anywhere close to a byte boundary and certainly not anywhere close to the limits a 32 bit number can hold (even signed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is : Yes, the limits are better, but more than 300K files are still
not advised.

In the article
[Keeping up with the new OneDrive 64 Bits Version](https://call4cloud.nl/2021/04/keeping-up-with-the-new-onedrive-64-bits-version/)
from April 14, 2021, OneDrive managed to upload 308K files.

However, the sync speed went down sharply above the 200K mark, and CPU time was
very high toward the end.

However, after the sync was finished, the user reported that new files were almost
immediately synced.